# Sharepoint 2013 top-level site with unique IP

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have a newly-configured Sharepoint 2013 server installation, which serves our company Intranet.
The new Intranet is now in service and operational.

Next, we need to create another top-level site which will serve as an Extranet portal for clients.
Sharepoint Central Administration does not provide a method by which a separate IP address can be
selected for a new site; instead, it provides port selection or entry only.

We need to route external traffic to the extranet site, which requires either a mapped internal IP
address or a different port. The main limitation we face is that most of our public-sector clients 
cannot use a non-standard port due to their firewall restrictions. So, this means a unique IP.

In the exhaustive research conducted concerning this issue, it appears that the "best practice"
receommended by Microsoft themselves is nothing but a workaround, where part of the process is
performed in SP Central Admin and the other half in IIS.

We have found many articles and blogs mentioning alternative ports, but none which address this situation directly.

Now we're trying to contend with Alternate Access Mappings, which are confusing our admins.

We really need the voice of experience from someone who has actually done this before.

Question: what is the correct way of achieving our goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your users will access the site based on a host name I guess, not on an IP address?
So, you will have an intranet under http://intranet and you now want to create an extranet under http://extranet.
The fact that extranet is on another IP address and routed to your SharePoint farm is not really an issue.

What you need to do, is to create another web application with as host name http://extranet
Your firewall / network hardware must then forward http://extranet to your SharePoint servers. IIS will see "extranet" and serve the extranet.

If your users will access it via the IP-address, it's similar. Instead of http://extranet, you enter http://ext.ip.addr as the host name.

Comment: Much appreciate the answer.

Comment: sorry, got kicked out before I could complete edits. Your assumptions are correct. Quoting, "What you need to do, is to create another web application with as host name http://extranet", yes this clearly is the case. But how is this achieved? The 'New' button is clicked in Central Admin->Manage Web Applications, and CA keeps insisting that we create the application on the same server 'spsvr' but with a different port number. It does not provide a method to set the IP address at creation. This is the sticking point. Any further hints?

Comment: Enter a value in the "host header" field. Then SharePoint will allow you to set the port to 80.

Comment: Yes, this method is known to us. However, our internal routing requires an IP address, not a host header. So far, it sounds like there exist nothing but ways **around** what our actual goal is. Is this your intended position? Thx

Comment: No, it's not a workaround. Web requests all work with a host header , which is a HEADER in the HTTP request. That may be an IP address, or a DNS name. In your case, users access the site via http://extranet, but your network hardware converts that to an IP address? Sounds very weird to me, never experienced that before. Yes, routing hardware requires an IP address to route to, but passes the host header (a header in the HTTP request) to the SharePoint server. Are you 100% sure the host header is changed by your network hardware? If that's the case, you set that IP address as the host header.

Comment: In case anyone arrives here looking for our answer to this issue, we decided just to create a new virtual machine and host the extranet on that one, using another Sharepoint installation.

Comment: That being said, it is apparent that with an appropriate level of expertise, Boland's answer would probably prove to be correct, so it is marked as the answer. We simply don't have the time in our budget to continue figuring it all out.